# A co--ection of images

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

What movie title from 2002 is hidden below?

---

[image]

Comment: Please could you confirm that the number in the cell four along and three down is 6.

Comment: @DanielS yes 6 is correct

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The hidden 2002 movie is:

> [**ICE AGE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Age_(2002_film))

To understand why, it's best to consider the solution in several steps.

**Step 1:**

First, identify all of the images.

> There's a helpful hint for each, in that the number in each box indicates the *word length*:
>
>  Row 1: POWDER, ROOT, HAND, SEA, CROSS, UNIT
>  Row 2: PIE, FRUIT, STREET, MEDAL, CHEESE, COLD
>  Row 3: CLOTHES, PAPER, STAR, RUBIK'S, CIRCLE, ALE

**Step 2:**

Now look at the colours of the numbers.

> Each colour is used 3 times across the puzzle. Let's group these images in terms of their colours in common:
>
>  Blue: POWDER, MEDAL, STAR
>  Dark red: ROOT, UNIT, RUBIK'S
>  Grey: HAND, CROSS, CLOTHES
>  Slate blue: SEA, STREET, PAPER
>  Orange: PIE, CHEESE, ALE
>  Red: FRUIT, COLD, CIRCLE

**Step 3:**

Next...

> ...find a word that connects each triplet, by forming other words or phrases when placed before or after them:
>
>  Blue = **BRONZE**: [Bronze POWDER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_gold), Bronze MEDAL, [Bronze STAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze_Star_Medal)
>  Dark red = **CUBE**: Cube ROOT, [UNIT Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_cube), RUBIK'S Cube
>  Grey = **IRON**: (govern with an) Iron HAND, [Iron CROSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Cross), CLOTHES Iron
>  Slate blue = **WALL**: SEA Wall, [Wall STREET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_Street), WallPAPER
>  Orange = **CREAM**: Cream PIE, Cream CHEESE, [Cream ALE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream_ale)
>  Red = **STONE**: Stone FRUIT, Stone COLD, Stone CIRCLE

**Step 4:**

Now notice the border colours of each boxes. Specifically...

> ...note that each set of boxes - whether yellow-bordered or lilac-bordered - comprises a set of three of the categories we just found.
>
>  i.e. Yellow bordered boxes comprise all Dark red, Orange, and Slate blue groups; Lilac bordered boxes comprise all Blue, Grey, and Red groups.
>
>  Now, the connections we just found in Step 3 for these two trios of groups can themselves be linked in exactly the same 'before-or-after' way:
>
>  Dark red (CUBE) & Slate blue (WALL) & Orange (CREAM) = **ICE**: Ice CUBE, [Ice WALL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_wall), Ice CREAM.
>
>  Blue (BRONZE) & Grey (IRON) & Red (STONE) = **AGE**: BRONZE Age, IRON Age, STONE Age.

**Step 5:**

Put these together, and we have our answer!

> ICE AGE

As for the title...

> We are supposed to infer that this isn't just a co**LL**ection of images, but that this puzzle also involves the co**NN**ection of images!

Comment: This is co--ect :) Great job!